# How to manage with Atom XML response in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have  write web application in Spring. In one service i have receive ATOM XML data using RestTemplate, but i use String.class to represent them. I want to represent ATOM data in class with appropriate attributes and i dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/feed/AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter.html)

Comment: Can you make me example of usage please? I dont much understand it